back4app flutter sdk is not installing

flutter pub add parse_server_sdk_flutter The current Dart SDK version
is 3.4.3.
Because parse_server_sdk_flutter <3.0.0 doesn't support null safety
and parse_server_sdk_flutter >=3.1.0 <3.1.2 depends on
parse_server_sdk ^3.1.0, parse_server_sdk_flutter <3.0.0-∞ or >=3.1.0
<3.1.2-∞ requires parse_server_sdk ^3.1.0. And because
parse_server_sdk_flutter >=3.0.0 <3.1.0 depends on parse_server_sdk
^3.0.0, parse_server_sdk_flutter <3.1.2 requires parse_server_sdk
^3.0.0. And because parse_server_sdk >=3.0.0 <3.1.0 depends on http
^0.13.1 and parse_server_sdk_flutter >=3.1.2 <3.1.3 depends on
parse_server_sdk ^3.1.1, parse_server_sdk_flutter <3.1.3 requires http
^0.13.1 or parse_server_sdk ^3.1.0. Because parse_server_sdk ^3.1.2
depends on http ^0.13.4 and parse_server_sdk >=3.1.0 <3.1.2 depends on
http ^0.13.3, parse_server_sdk ^3.1.0 requires http ^0.13.3. Thus,
parse_server_sdk_flutter <3.1.3 requires http ^0.13.1. And because
parse_server_sdk_flutter ^3.1.3 depends on package_info_plus ^1.4.2
which depends on package_info_plus_web ^1.0.5,
parse_server_sdk_flutter <4.0.0 requires http ^0.13.1 or
package_info_plus_web ^1.0.5. And because package_info_plus_web>
=1.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http ^0.13.0 and parse_server_sdk_flutter >=5.0.0 <5.0.1 requires SDK version=2.18.0
<3.1.0, parse_server_sdk_flutter <4.0.0-∞ or >=5.0.0 <5.0.1-∞ requires
http ^0.13.0. And because parse_server_sdk_flutter ^4.0.0 depends on
parse_server_sdk ^4.0.0 which depends on http ^0.13.5,
parse_server_sdk_flutter <5.0.1 requires http ^0.13.0. And because
parse_server_sdk_flutter ^7.0.0 depends on parse_server_sdk ^5.1.3 and
parse_server_sdk_flutter >=5.1.1 <7.0.0 depends on parse_server_sdk
^5.1.2, parse_server_sdk_flutter <5.0.1-∞ or >=5.1.1 <8.0.0-∞ requires
http ^0.13.0 or parse_server_sdk ^5.1.2. And because
parse_server_sdk_flutter >=5.1.0 <5.1.1 depends on parse_server_sdk
^5.1.1 and parse_server_sdk_flutter >=5.0.1 <5.1.0 depends on
parse_server_sdk ^5.1.0, parse_server_sdk_flutter <8.0.0 requires http
^0.13.0 or parse_server_sdk ^5.1.0. And because parse_server_sdk>
=5.0.0 <5.1.1 requires SDK version=2.18.0 <3.1.0 and parse_server_sdk_flutter >=8.0.0 depends on parse_server_sdk   ^6.4.0,
every version of parse_server_sdk_flutter requires http ^0.13.0 or
parse_server_sdk ^5.1.1 or ^6.4.0. And because parse_server_sdk>
=5.1.1 <7.0.0 depends on http ^0.13.5 and google_fonts >=4.0.5 depends on http ^1.0.0, google_fonts >=4.0.5 is incompatible with
parse_server_sdk_flutter. So, because cleamba depends on both
google_fonts ^6.2.1 and parse_server_sdk_flutter any, version solving
failed.
The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.2.2 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to
enable null safety. For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

When I tried to install parse server SDK on my flutter project its not installing. I am getting this type of message in my terminal. I have also update my google fonts to 6.2.1 or higher and I have also run flutter upgrade command on my project.
SDK LINK : https://www.back4app.com/docs/flutter/parse-sdk/parse-flutter-sdk
Expectation: I could able to install the Parse SDK successfully to my flutter project.
Reality: My terminal shows the above message despite the successful installation.

Try changing the SDK version in the pubspec.yaml like below.
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.3.1 <4.0.0"

And try to import like below,


Doesn't work for me too
